# Get an attribute of a div class from another div class for angular protractor test

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

I am very new in Angular protractor test. In my app, I am implementing Protractor framework for test automation. Now I have an step where a dialog is appear based on the button click. Inside dialog there is a dialog content which contains two div. One is showing if the chart is loaded successfully, another will be shown if there is an error message. Now I want to implement an if-else condition, which would check which content is available at that moment. Bu the problem is this if condition is not executing. It always goes to else condition even-if there exist the error-content.

Here is my dialog component class

```
<div class="action-row-align dialog-component">
<div class="dialog-content" mat-dialog-content >
    <div *ngIf="isLoading && !errorText" class="loading-content">
        <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
        <h6>{{ loadingInfoText }}</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="error-content" *ngIf="!isLoading && errorText" >
        <mat-card>
            <mat-card-title>{{ 'Error' | translate }}</mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-content>{{ errorText }}</mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>

    </div>

 </div>
```

My hasClass method is

```
    export class Utility {
    static hasClass = (element, className) => element.getAttribute('class').then((classes) => classes.split(' ').indexOf(className) !== -1)
}
```

And here is my test condition

```
let dialog = element(by.css('.dialog-component'));
let dialogContent = element(by.css('.dialog-content'));
        await click.onto(option);
        await expect(dialogContent.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
        if (await Utility.hasClass( await dialogContent, 'error-content') === true) {
                await console.log(' chart error' );
        } else {
        await expect(dialog.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
        await expect(chart.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a dot in your selector.
Should be:
`let dialogContent = element(by.css('.dialog-content'));`

Edited:
The problem is you are trying to check whether `dialogContent` elemnent has `'error-content'` class. It doesn't. `dialogContent`'s child has it's class. You need to get child of that's selector.

Edited2:
I'd simplify wholde code:

```
const dialog = element(by.css('.dialog-component'));
const errorContent = element(by.css('.dialog-content > .error-content'));
await click.onto(option);
await expect(dialogContent.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);

if (await errorContent.isPresent()) {
    await console.log(' chart error' );
} else {
    await expect(dialog.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    await expect(chart.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
}
```

Comment: Can you please pase a console output?

Comment: Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .step-chart)
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .step-chart)

Comment: this message is showing for else condition, where a chart will be shown if everything goes well. But in that case i want to execute if condition, which will show a error message in console

Comment: how can I check if condition now. Could you please explain.

Comment: I see in dialog content has two child class. one is loading content another is error conten

Comment: I'm not sure how `await` works, If it resolves a promise - try my solution. Let me know how it works.

Comment: I got this messge No element found using locator: By(css selector, .dialog-content > .error-content)
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .dialog-content > .error-content)

Comment: error-content would not appear all the time. only if the dialog has no chart then